# MySQL specify default value when data has incorrect values

Tags: mysql

I have a csv file where some integer fields are blank (e.g. , ,) or have an NA value (e.g. ,NA  ,).  When I load the data (LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE...)  into a table MySQL correctly warns that the fields have incorrect integer values, however it inserts a 0, not the DEFAULT value specified in the CREATE TABLE DDL, into the columns.  Is there any way I can specify the value to use in case of incorrect values in a data file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [load data infile default value not inserting in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10897277/load-data-infile-default-value-not-inserting-in-table); see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32939947/mysql-load-data-local-infile-with-default-timestamp-column-value) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591170/mysql-how-do-i-insert-now-date-when-doing-a-load-data-infile)

Comment: I don't see this as a duplicate.  My table has default values in the columns but the defaults are not being used in cases where the data file has incorrect integer values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you need to 'cleanse' the incoming data, there are two techniques to consider.  Suppose the column `foo` needs to be `-1` to represent `"NA"`:

Using `@variables`...

`LOAD` into and `@variable`, then use `SET` to manipulate the value while storing it.  There are examples in the docs. In your case you might use something like `SET foo := IF(@foo = 'NA', -1, @foo)` *inside* the `LOAD DATA` statement.

Using a temp table...

Instead of `LOADing` directly into the target table, load into a separate table (possible `TEMPORARY`).  Then have a few SQL statements to manipulate the data in that table before copying to the "real" table.  In your case:  `UPDATE tmp SET foo = -1 WHERE foo = 'NA';`.  Then `INSERT INTO real SELECT * FROM tmp;`.  Note `foo` would be `VARCHAR` in `tmp` in spite of being `INT` in `real`.

The temp table approach can handle more complex transformations.

Comment: Two excellent suggestions, thank you.  It would be nice if there were an option to LOAD/INSERT to use a column's default value in case of incorrect data.

Comment: bugs.mysql.com accepts "feature requests".